# (Screen-)Record multiple iOS devices with CoreMediaIO

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mirroring, screen-recording

I'm currently trying to achieve streaming of iOS-Devices in realtime.
I'd like to use the AVFoundation / CoreMediaIO with a Mac via cable (https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/macos-media-capture-using-coremediaio/).

CoreMediaIO however only supports one device at a time (source: https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/macos-media-capture-using-coremediaio/).

Is there any way to remove the CoreMediaIO one-device-at-a-time limit?

Thank you in advance!

Best Regards

Comment: Solved? I alse the problem